# Embedding Lua with Xcode

Tags: c++, macos, xcode4, lua

I'm having trouble getting Lua 5.2.0 to work in Xcode 4. I built it using `make` linked in liblua.a, added the header path, and included it with `Extern "C"`. I get no linker Errors. However when I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    lua_State *ls = lua_newstate(0, 0);

    lua_close(ls);
    return 0;
}
```

I get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1, address=0x0)` on line 11. Which I assume is telling me that I am in fact trying to make a call to something that does not exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a NULL memory allocation function to `lua_newstate`. No wonder it crashes. Perhaps you want to use `luaL_newstate`?